# count numbers in the list are between 1 and 10 in python

Tags: python

Im looking to create a program in python that asks the user to enter a list of numbers in [] format.

It then must count and display how many of those numbers in the list are between 1 and 10, 10 and 20,
20 and 30 ect.

Here is what i have so far.

```
my_num = [int(i) for i in raw_input("Enter numbers... ").split(",")]

the_list = eval(my_num)

number = 0

if 1<= my_num and my_num <=10:
    number = number + 1
```

Comment: By _number_ you mean _integer_, or not only? Do you care about the precision in case you accept not only integers? Also please never use `eval`, always use type conversion / casting (eg. `int('10')` is better than `eval('10')`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```py
import itertools

numbers = sorted(map(int, raw_input().split(",")))
for k, g in itertools.groupby(numbers, lambda x: x // 10):
    print k, list(g)
```

This will give you groups of numbers, and you can count the instances in the group with calls to `len()`.  For instance, replace

```py
    # print k, list(g)
    print k, len(list(g))
```

The important thing is to sort the numbers first.

With this as input:

```py
1, 5, 6, 89, 43, 43, 25, 76, 12, 32, 23, 25, 27, 13, 5, 7

0 [1, 5, 5, 6, 7]
1 [12, 13]
2 [23, 25, 25, 27]
3 [32]
4 [43, 43]
7 [76]
8 [89]
```

Or the output with the len call instead:

```py
0 5
1 2
2 4
3 1
4 2
7 1
8 1
```

Which could then be formatted like this:

```py
print "%d - %d: %d" % (k * 10 + 1, (k + 1) * 10, len(list(g))
```

Yielding:

```py
 1 - 10: 5
11 - 20: 2
21 - 30: 4
31 - 40: 1
41 - 50: 2
71 - 80: 1
81 - 90: 1
```

Comment: More compatible (you still have `raw_input` instead of `input` and `print` as statement), but `//` is mostly because you can do `from __future__ import division` in Python 2.x and you will get strange results here. It is better to stick to `//` because of that. I have also added `<!-- language-all: lang-py -->`, so the part after `//` is not grayed out as a comment, but seemingly you rolled that change out ;)

Comment: Good call on the language-all tag.  I couldn't see it in the edit and figured it was an accidental edit as it showed everything changed.

Comment: I see that it counts the integers within the ranges but displays only the interger range entered.  So if there are no intergers betwween 1 - 10 then there's no display but I would like one.

Answer (score 2):

Using a `Counter` is efficicent, because you only need to iterate over the list once

```
>>> L = [1, 5, 6, 89, 43, 43, 25, 76, 12, 32, 23, 25, 27, 13, 5, 7]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(x//10 for x in L)
Counter({0: 5, 2: 4, 1: 2, 4: 2, 3: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1})
>>> sorted(Counter(x//10 for x in L).items())
[(0, 5), (1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 1), (4, 2), (7, 1), (8, 1)]

>>> for k,v in sorted(Counter(x//10 for x in L).items()):
...     print "%d - %d: %d"%(k*10, k*10+9, v)
...
0 - 9: 5
10 - 19: 2
20 - 29: 4
30 - 39: 1
40 - 49: 2
70 - 79: 1
80 - 89: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

use `len()` and list comprehension:

```
>>> lis=[1, 5, 6, 89, 43, 43, 25, 76, 12, 32, 23, 25, 27, 13, 5, 7]

>>> [(i,[x for x in lis if x//10==i]) for i in range(0,(max(lis)//10)+1)]
[(0, [1, 5, 6, 5, 7]), (1, [12, 13]), (2, [25, 23, 25, 27]), (3, [32]), (4, [43, 43]), (5, []), (6, []), (7, [76]), (8, [89])]
```

for length use `len()`:

```
>>> [(i,len([x for x in lis if x//10==i])) for i in range(0,(max(lis)//10)+1)]
[(0, 5), (1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 0), (6, 0), (7, 1), (8, 1)]
```

Comment: The OP wants counts for each range of 10.  1-10, 11-20, 21-30, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood, you want to determine the number of numbers in different ranges: [1;10], [11; 20]; [21; 30], ..., [91; 100]

```
# Example of user input
your_list = [2, 10, 93, 1, 20]

# All the ranges' right part (sorry if my english is bad). my_ranges = [10, 20, 30, ..., 100]
my_ranges = []

# Array determining how many of those numbers in the list are in [1; 10], [11; 20], ..., [91; 100]
numbers = []

for i in range(1, 11):
    my_ranges.append(i*10)
    numbers.append(0)

for i in range(0, len(your_list)):
    out = False
    j = 0
    while not out and j<len(my_ranges):
        if your_list[i] <= my_ranges[j]:
            out = True
            numbers[j]+=1
        j+=1

for i in range(0, len(numbers)):
    print "Number of numbers in ["+str(my_ranges[i]+1-10)+";"+str(my_ranges[i])+"] = "+str(numbers[i])
```

Comment: With this strategy you need to know ahead of time how many ranges to account for.  What if the input is 1,2,1000000,4000000, for example.

Comment: Im not looking for an input that high. The ranges are to 100 in intervals or 10.  I also would like to input several sets of 1 to 100 but I havent got that far yet.

Comment: The simplest way for you would be to just create an array wich contains the right part of ranges.
So, if the ranges are to 100 you can do:

my_ranges = []
numbers = []
for i in ranges(1, 10):
   my_ranges.append(i*10)
   numbers.append(0)

So that the array my_ranges would contain [10, 20, ..., 100] and the array numbers would be [0,0, ...0]

Comment: So when I say sets of 1 -100 you're saying array in stead of sets.

Comment: Yes, the arrays are for the ranges only. Why would you input several sets of 1 to 100 after that? The list "your_list" is input list which has been entered by the user. I am not sure I understand... :S

Comment: well it's just that.  I would think you could just repeat the code to acheive this.

Comment: I've just realized there were crazy mistakes in my code (must be sleeping time). I've just changed the code and added what I commented previously. It's just a very simple solution I guess... Hope it helps :S...

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily the most simple way to do this, but the [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) can be a useful substitute for `eval`.

As for counting how many are in each group of ten numbers, the `itertools` module has a [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```py
import ast
import itertools


the_input = raw_input("Enter numbers... ")

# Lazy way to parse '[1,2,3]' into [1,2,3]
the_list = ast.literal_eval(the_input)

# Or, parse it manually (this is probably better in this case):
the_list = [int(x) for x in the_input.strip("[]").split(",")]

# Group by dividing number by 10, the result as an integer (15//10==1)
# This means 0-9 are in "group 0", 10-19 are in "group 1" etc
groups = itertools.groupby(the_list, key = lambda k: k // 10)

# Show stats for each block of ten
for group_count, group_members in groups:
    print "There were {count} numbers in {start}-{end}".format(
        count = len(list(group_members)),
        start = group_count * 10, # 15/10 becomes 1, then we do 1*10 for 10
        end = group_count * 10 + 9) # and 1*10+9 to get 19 (displayed as "in 10-19"
```

Example run:

```py
$ python script.py
Enter numbers... [1,2, 11,12,13, 22,23, 44,45,46,47]
There were 2 numbers in 0-9
There were 3 numbers in 10-19
There were 2 numbers in 20-29
There were 4 numbers in 40-49
```

To tweak it to group 1-10, 11-20 and so on, just change the line `group =` line like so:

```py
groups = itertools.groupby(the_list, key = lambda k: k // 10 + 1)
```

Alternatively, a bit simpler:

```py
the_input = raw_input("Enter numbers... ")

# Parse "[1,2,3]" into a list of numbers
the_list = [int(x) for x in the_input.strip("[]").split(",")]

group_counter = {}

for number in the_list:
    group_start = (number // 10) * 10
    group_end = group_start + 9
    group_name = "%s-%s" % (group_start, group_end)

    group_counter.setdefault(group_name, 0)
    group_counter[group_name] += 1


for name, count in group_counter.items():
    # Note that the sorting is wrong
    print "There were %s in %s" % (count, name)
```

You could also use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) if you are using Python 2.7 or higher

Comment: Thank you for that explanation.  It does the job.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Count total number of numbers in the list
> 2. Sum and Average of all the numbers in the list
> 3. Count and sum of all the odd numbers in the list
> 4. Count and sum of all the even numbers in the list
> 5. Find the largest number in the list
> 6. Find the smallest number in the list
>
> Display all the values with appropriate titles.

```
listNo = [6,8,10,44,33,21,7,1,0,2]
c = 0
s = 0
avg = 0
sOdd = 0
sEven = 0
cOdd = 0
cEven = 0
for i in listNo :
    c += 1
    s = s+i
    avg = s/c
    if i % 2 == 0 :
        sEven = sEven + i
        cEven = cEven + 1
    else :
        sOdd = sOdd + i
        cOdd = cOdd + 1
print ("total number of numbers in the list  : ", c)
print("sum of all numbers : ",s)
print("average of all numbers : ",avg)
print("count odd numbers : ",cOdd)
print("sum of odd numbers : ",sOdd)
print("count even numbers : ",cEven)
print("sum of odd numbers : ",sEven)
print("largest number in the list : " ,max(listNo))
print("smallest number in the list  : ",min(listNo))
```